# Best practice about cron jobs

Tags: linux, cron

```
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronjobs/check_nginx.sh
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronjobs/check_php-fpm.sh
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronjobs/check_named.sh
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronjobs/check_vsftpd.sh
*/2 * * * * /etc/cronjobs/check_mariadb.sh
```

Hey guys, these lines are scripts that checks if some services are up and running but I'm not sure if 2 min is enough to guarantee stability or even if they are too much for a small vps(512mb ram, 1 vCPU).

When I set  */2   for all of them, they will be executed at the same time? I know that is something like a queue but I'm unsure about if this is a good practice.

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Yes, they will; if you want them sequential, try `*/2 * * * *   /etc/cronjobs/a.sh ; /etc/cronjobs/b.sh ; /etc/cronjobs/c.sh ... `.

Answer (score 4):

They will be executed more or less concurrently (considering they are on 1 CPU machine). If you are worried about them being down for up to 2 minutes before the checker gets to them, consider running them under something like supervisord / systemd / init, or some other mechanism that will instantly detect if they have died and restart them.

If you are worried about 2 minutes of downtime, that implies you are running some sort of production load where 512M /1CPU does seem rather cramped.